# Getting desired output + lots of clutter printed on decision tree feature importance (ValueError: continuous is not supported)

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree, feature-selection

I have the following code to do feature ranking and some cross validation on it.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

dtr = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state =  42)
# Train model
model = dtr.fit(X_airbnb, y_airbnb)

feat_importances = pd.DataFrame(model.feature_importances_, index = X_airbnb.columns, columns=["Importance"])
feat_importances.sort_values(by='Importance', ascending=False, inplace=True)

output = cross_validate(dtr, X_airbnb, y_airbnb, cv=2, scoring = 'accuracy', return_estimator =True)

for idx,estimator in enumerate(output['estimator']):
    print("Features sorted by their score for estimator {}:".format(idx))
    feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(estimator.feature_importances_,
                                       index = X_airbnb.columns,
                                        columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance', ascending=False)
    print(feature_importances)
```

The output gives feature ranking, but also gives me a **ValueError: continuous is not supported**. The full error code is the following

```
d:\ITU\CalculusandStatistics\KDS_Statistics_GroupProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:776: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ITU\CalculusandStatistics\KDS_Statistics_GroupProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 767, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "d:\ITU\CalculusandStatistics\KDS_Statistics_GroupProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py", line 220, in __call__
    return self._score(
  File "d:\ITU\CalculusandStatistics\KDS_Statistics_GroupProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py", line 268, in _score
    return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred, **self._kwargs)
  File "d:\ITU\CalculusandStatistics\KDS_Statistics_GroupProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_param_validation.py", line 192, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\ITU\CalculusandStatistics\KDS_Statistics_GroupProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py", line 221, in accuracy_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "d:\ITU\CalculusandStatistics\KDS_Statistics_GroupProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py", line 106, in _check_targets
    raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: continuous is not supported
```

This is followed by the desired output, and then a repeat of the error.

The main problem is that I dont see how there is anything wrong on the results. I would like to save the feature_importances to a dataframe but it wont let me.

Comment: Please edit your question to include any errors as text. [Images of errors/data are not useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I have written the error code in the title as well as above the image. I will however write the whole thing down if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Further googling has shown me how to fix the error. First problem was that I should not refer to X as just X but as X.values, second error was that the scoring I was looking for was the accuracy metric, which is useful in classification tasks but not in regression tasks, I can instead replace it with any of the metrics shown here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).